# Easy to use C++ IDE for use with C++17 and beyond

Tags: c++, programming, dark-theme

I have been building console apps for a short while now with Dev C++. I would like to ween off of it and get a more modern IDE with better features and better visuals (like dark mode) and the ability to use the more modern versions of C++. Some of my code requires C++17 and it's very difficult for me to setup Dev C++ with it for some reason. I got it working out of sheer luck and I am afraid if something goes wrong it's not going to be easy to figure out again. So I am wanting to move on.

I mainly just need modern IDE that is simple to setup, looks nice and getting C++17 or higher on it is done in a few simple clicks. (I want to keep up to date). Is there such a thing? Visual Studio is too hard for me to figure out how to setup properly, and I have tried CodeLite (which looks amazing!) but even though I installed the compiler and it recognizes it - my build options are greyed out. Isn't there something simple out there that just.... works?

Comment: You can try http://www.codeblocks.org/